# Existence of Green's Function for Dirichlet Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Does anyone know where I can find a proof of the existence of Green's function, $G(x,x_0)$ on any nice enough domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Edit: This is for Laplace's problem

Comment: For which problem?

Comment: Laplace's problem

Comment: I assume this is for the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation, though clarification would be nice. If I am correct, any text on classical potential theory, e.g. the text by Armitage and Gardiner, will have a proof. This particular text is probably more general than you want, but it does contain most of a proof for the case of a $C^2$ boundary (some of it is left to exercises).